# SwipeEnabled: false option is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have trouble with react-navigation 5 on my react-native project, I want to disable drawer swipes but keep close drawer by click outside it. I have read about this property on react-navigation docs. GestureEnabled property works, but it dismisses close drawer by click

here's screen

```
const Home = ({ route, navigation }) => {
};
Home.navigationOptions = () => ({
  swipeEnabled: false,
  edgeWidth: 0,
});
export default observer(Home);
```

here's navigator

`````
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Головна"
          edgeWidth={wp(100)}
          drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
        >
          <Drawer.Screen name="Головна" component={Home} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Історія" component={MyTrips} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Мій профіль" component={Profile} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Про водія" component={AboutDriver} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Мої бонуси" component={MyBonuses} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Мої місця" component={MyPlaces} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
````
`````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you don't need to disable swipe for specific screen

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Головна"
      edgeWidth={wp(100)}
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
      screenOptions={{swipeEnabled: false}}
    >
      ...
    </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

how to programmatically achieve this from within the screen using setParams and gestureEnabled? I'm following this [page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#gestureenabled) and was expecting following to work:

```
props.navigation.setParams({ gestureEnabled: false })

"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.3",
```